# kernel upgrade from 5.10.0-16-amd64 to 5.10.0-18-amd64 debian 11 bullseye

Tags: linux-kernel

i'm trying to upgrade from kernel version 5.10.0-16-amd64 to kernel version 5.10.0-18-amd64 but can't seem to find the tar or the .sig files, any ideas where to find them to download?

Answer (score 1):

You’ll find the tarballs and signature files here:

- http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/l/linux/linux_5.10.158.orig.tar.xz
- http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/l/linux/linux_5.10.158-2.debian.tar.xz
- http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/l/linux/linux_5.10.158-2.dsc

You’ll only need these if you want to rebuild the kernel packages yourself. In the general case, you should upgrade the kernel with `apt upgrade` (as root).

Comment: I tried to install these sources but it installs 5.10.158 not  5.10.0-18-amd64

Comment: Why are you installing the source packages? What’s wrong with installing the binary packages? And the current version of the 5.10.0-18 packages *is* 5.10.158-2.